# Is libre the only English single-word adjective signifying 'liberty' without also meaning 'at no monetary cost'?

Tags: synonyms

The Wikipedia entry [Gratis versus libre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_Libre) contains the following text:

> Libre /ˈliːbrə/ in English is adopted from the various Romance languages, ultimately descending from the Latin word lībere; its origin is closely related to liberty. It denotes "the state of being free", as in "liberty" or "having freedom". The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) considers libre to be obsolete,[2] but the word has come back into limited[3] use. Unlike gratis, libre appears in few English dictionaries,[3] although there is no other English single-word adjective signifying "liberty" exclusively, without also meaning "at no monetary cost".

If there truly is no such word, then I must grudgingly accept the ugliness of Libre. I must admit that nothing springs readily to mind. Is there such a word?

EDIT: The basis of this question is that the people who coined (or revived) the term Libre didn't do so lightly. They were obviously of the opinion that it was necessary.

Comment: Did you look for synonyms for "free" in a thesaurus?

Comment: Depends on what type of liberty you're talking about here—there are many. A few one-word adjectives to describe some of them: unhindered, unencumbered, unfettered, untied, unattached, unbound. Spot the pattern there?

Comment: Doesn't the word _liberty_ itself, have no association with being _at no cost_?

Comment: No, one does ***not*** pronounce it  `/ˈlibrə/` in English as though it were the constellation *Libra*, but rather `/ˈlibreɪ/`.

Comment: @Neil In a word, no.

Comment: This is just a rehash of the whole ***“free** software”* demi-duplicity of Richard Stallman’s, which gave rise to Tim O’Reilly’s ***“open** software”* as a less-dishonest  formulation for what boils down to virtually the same thing. Richard should have used something like *unencumbered* or *unfettered*, but he wanted to be cute, and perhaps even tricksy, so much so that it  borders on being intentionally deceptive. Bottom line is that it confuses people, and this is bad. Tim used a nice simple little word, which works much better, and doesn’t make people think the wrong thing.

Comment: @tchrist can you give me an example please?

Comment: @Neil Sorry, I misread your triple-negatived sentence into a positive.  The word *liberty* has no cost element associated with it; the concept may be otherwise.

Comment: @tchrist - the schwa is correct, and barely there; it exists only to allow the "r" to be heard at all. It is an English approximation of the French emphatic pronunciation of the word; in ordinary conversational use, `/ˈliːbᴙə/` becomes `[lib]`.

Comment: @bye An actual French pronunciation, really? Never heard that. Everybody I know gives it an anglicized Spanish or Italian pronunciation instead.

Comment: @tchrist - That's a US-ian thing (where Spanish is a heavy secondary language throughout the country, with a few regional exceptions). The rest of the world uses the anglicised French pronunciation.

Comment: @tchrist I thought 'open source' was suggested by Christine Peterson and adopted by a group of people including ES Raymond on January 1998 for Netscape.

Comment: @tchrist 'open source' is ***not sufficient*** for expressing the free-as-in-speech variant of 'free' in 'free' software. In my own experience: I have seen software that are 'open source' but contrary to the popular expectation use such a restrictive license that you can *not* modify it or build upon it at all. On the other hand, for example, Gnu has a definition page for 4 freedoms meant by 'free' at [What is free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html). Creative Commons differentiates too. Compare [free licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_license).

Comment: I was thinking of the word ***unrestricted***, which sounds pretty *'libre'*. The thing it starts out as 'un-', I can understand that some people find that intimidating. On the other hand, I find it more ***clear*** than either 'free' or 'libre'.

Answer (score 3):

There is no good general-purpose word for this in English. That's why we have the phrases "free as in speech" and "free as in beer." You can say "freed" (as in "freedman") or "liberated" or "at liberty," but those all have more specific connotations.

Answer (score 2):

**Liberated** is the adjective most closely associated with liberty.

Comment: Although that implies missing clothing items...  which I suppose is another meaning of the word **free**  :)